# Does my location affect my blog's views

Tags: blogs, blogger

lately i noticed that most my views are from Africa, but the subject of my blog is intended for everyone, it's written in English and have a plenty of tutorials. so why all viewers are from Africa ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe people in other continents aren't very interested in what you have to say. But more likely your blog isn't well known and is being visited by bots or spammers in Africa sniffing your site for email addresses or places to post comments. There is also the possibility that whatever you are using to get analytics is broken.

Comment: there are no bots or a very small number of bots in my blog, that's because the source of the trafic is always a know web browser and windows OS. i counted ...